# Prevent resize of background image cover in Ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm working on a **hybrid app** in **Ionic**. I set a background of div like this:

```
.loginForm {
  background: url(../img/bg1-web.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
}
```

If the keyboard appears in the form, the background image resizes because the height of device reduces.

This is the normal behaviour and this is right. But I would like that the background image not resizes and stay fixed. I tryed with `background-attachment` set to `fixed` but not work.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

instead.

Comment: Not work. The image loses the aspect ratio and is still moving.

Comment: Your problem is very badly written. You want it to occupy all, even if the height decrease size,? Then just remove the property `background-size` and `background-fixed`.

http://codepen.io/rdsedmundo/pen/KgzpVg

Comment: You're right, I have not explained well! I want that background image occupies all but that adapts by different screen size (phone and tablet devices). So I solved by using css media queries: I set different background width and height for each viewport. In this way the image preserve the aspect ratio and remains fixed even if the device's keyboard appears. Thank you very much for your help!